# SQL 2008 R2 Minimum permissions role to allow user to extract data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to give minimum permissions to allow a user (vendor) via Windows Authentication to my 2008 R2 server/database.
I have also installed BIDS (not sure that is relevant to my two questions):

1) The vendor will login via RDP to the desktop of the Windows 2008 R2 server and they will be extracting data from my 2008 R2 SQL PRODUCTION database. Without knowing how they will extract, I can't test an extract with my test account. I want to make sure I am giving only enough permissions and not too much.

I believe they need they need db_datareader role to my production database.
The vendor says they need Data Reader access.
Is this all they need to do an extract? (No Sysadmin role I assume.)

2) I do need to allow them access to a database where they can store their own packages for scheduled daily, weekly, monthly extracts.  I planned on creating the database and giving the vendor account dbo ownership and sysadmin role. Is this what I need here?